# Hard refresh in vim (not :so %)

Tags: vim

Sometimes in vim I'll need to exit the vimrc file and enter back into it to update changes (for example if I'm editing other files related to it). To do this I'll normally do:

```
:wq
$ vim
ctrl-o ctrl-o " in vim
```

Would there be a way to do this all within vim? Something like:

```
:wq | !vim %
```

Additionally, why does it require me to do `ctrl-o` two times to go to the previous buffer (it almost seems like the first `ctrl-o` does nothing)?

---

**Update**: Please note that I am aware of doing `:so %` or `:so $MYVIMRC`, etc. My question here is how do I basically reset 100% of the things to whatever are in my current files? That is, unset ALL mappings, variables, etc. that may have been updated, removed, etc; update **ALL** files that may have changed (functions, plugins, colorschemes, etc.). I don't think "Running `:so %` on 20 files" is a good solution here, which is why my current solution is to close the file and re-open it.

Comment: what exactly do you get from exiting vim and entering it again? Can't you just leave it open?

Comment: @Chelz I suppose so (that's the goal), but let's just say I change ten files in my `.vim` directory, some in the `after/` directories, etc. etc., how can I resource all the necessary files so that I have an up-to-current load of everything? Removing any unused mappings, stuff like that...

Comment: IMO, it's not worth any optimization: `:xa` to exit; then re-launch vim; then press "backtick-zero" to reopen the last file.

Comment: @Matt yea I think that might be the best approach. Regarding backtick-zero, are marks 0-9 the ten most recently-opened files?

Comment: @Matt also, what does the `a` in `:xa` do? It doesn't show as one of the options when I type `:h :x`.

Comment: @David542 See `:h mark-motions` Not "a recently opened file", but rather "ten last exit points"; `:h :xa` - no space, not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can source your `.vimrc`, but that doesn't completely reset Vim.  If you want to just restart Vim, then you can do so by re-execing it.

Vim doesn't provide a built-in way to exec processes from within it, since typically one doesn't want to replace one's editor with another process, but it is possible to do so with Perl or Ruby, as you see fit:

```
:perl exec "vim"
```

or

```
:ruby exec "vim"
```

This may or may not work on Windows, and it of course requires that your Vim version have been compiled with support for the appropriate interpreters.  Debian provides both in the `vim-nox`, `vim-gtk3`, and `vim-athena` packages, but not in `vim` or `vim-tiny`; Ubuntu, last I checked, did not provide Ruby support but did include Perl.

If you want to re-exec with the same buffer, you can use one of these:

```
:perl exec "vim", $curbuf->Name();
```

or

```
:ruby exec "vim", Vim::Buffer.current.name
```

Note that re-execing may cause your screen to be slightly messed up when exiting, so you may need to use `reset` to set it back to normal.

Comment: thanks, that works for me. Is there a way to grab `%` within the perl script?

Comment: thanks for that. One last question: how would I run the perl equivalent of ``:perl exec "vim normal!`0"`` ? In other words, `0 gets us back to the last exited file with the cursor in the same place.

Comment: think I got it: ``perl exec "vim", "-c", "normal!`0"``. Why does perl require `,` between spaces and it doesn't just allow entering in "vim -c ..." ?

Comment: Because you're calling a function and the `exec` function takes multiple arguments.  The parentheses are optional.  You can technically pass a shell command as a single string, but this doesn't work everywhere, has different error handling, and comes with potential security problems.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you had tried this but you can source your vimrc file from vim itself by typing

> :so $MYVIMRC

Answer (score -1):

In order to apply the changes, you don't have to exit vim and open it again, no need for a "hard refresh" :)
If you want to apply in on the .vimrc file itself, you can type

```
:so %
```

to apply the changes in another file, you can type:

```
:so ~/.vimrc #path to your .vimrc file
```

in normal mode, `Ctrl-O` takes you to where your cursor has been backward and `Ctrl-I` forward. You can check your jump list by typing `:jumps`, to clear your jumps :clearjumps

in insert mode, `Ctrl-O` escapes to normal mode and lets the user to do one normal mode command.

Comment: if you want to execute a command on multiple buffers, you can check the `:bufdo` command. `:h bufdo`